# Why is my page giving this error? Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object

Tags: magento

This is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object in WEBSITE/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 759
```

I am getting a plain white screen and then turned on error messages and this is what came up. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You have an error with xml an block.
On which page/url do you have this error?

I had this error on my product's details' page, so I guesses the problem was in `catalog.xml` in the base layout. The xml block `<catalog_product_view>` had a problem.

Copy `catalog.xml` from the default layout to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was an invalid catalog.xml. Try to validate your xml files first. I used the commandline tool xmllint.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is almost a year ago yet I encountered the same problem today.

And what I did is I flush the cache and rebuilding the indexes.  Hope this could help future programmers who will encounter same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your catalog.xml file. Copy the catalog.xml file from default folder and add it to your current theme folder. Problem will be solved.